# simple web.config file question asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

i am using windows authentication with my asp.net application

different users will have different access to parts of the website.

i would like to do something like this in the config file:

```
    <appSettings>
     <role1>
<user>agordon</user><user>jsmith</user>
     </role1>
<role2><user>dtodd</user><user>kveel</user></role2>
    </appSettings>
```

is this possible to do?

when authenticating i would then get the username like this:

```
string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

and check if that user exists in the specific role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<authorization>` element:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*" />
         <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You can then modify that for particular parts of your site:

```
<location path="Pages/Administration">
       <system.web>
          <authorization>
             <deny roles="*"/>
             <allow roles="Admin" />
          </authorization>
       </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: thank you, where do i specify which parts of the site this pertains to?

Comment: thanks so much can you help wiht this: http://serverfault.com/questions/304166/does-iis-server-have-to-be-on-domain-for-windows-authentication-and-roles

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this, but it's really not the best way.

The problem here is that appSettings are not controlled by the Web.Config schema, so you'll need to programatically enumerate appSettings in a horrible fashion:

```
if (configurationSettings.HasKey("Role1")) { ... }
else if (configurationSettings.HasKey("Role2")) { ... }
else if (configurationSettings.HasKey("Role3")) { ... }
//continue ad.nauseum; it's not fun - trust me!
```

I know it's not what you're asking, but If you're using normal ASP.Net webforms then it's a little it of a slog; in each page/control you need to find out the current user and then determine if that user has access and then redirect or continue.

If you use ASP.Net MVC, it's a lot cleaner as you do this with attributes.

```
Authorize(Roles = "Managers")]
public ActionResult CompanySecrets()
{
    return View();
}
```

What the code there is doing, is saying If the user doesn't have the Managers role, don't give them access.

To provide an opposite example, here's a similar method using Web form (msdn example):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311495

Comment: thanks so much. to be able to do roles i would have to go through crazy hoops right to get that to work?

Comment: Please explain the downvote; I've illustrated the problems with the method the OP asked about and provided two examples of a different way of solving the problem.

Comment: No no, Role authentication is fine - the problem is doing it via AppSettings. The link to MSDN I provided shows how to do Role authentication, you'll just have to work out a storage method to associate your access with the role that's reported.

Comment: i tried to get roles to work but its a HUGE pain because i need to install access from the IIS to the domain controller

Comment: Is your IIS server not in the same domain as the Active Directory then ?

Comment: the iis server is local to my machine and my machine is on the domain

Comment: @RussC let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2752/discussion-between-i-and-russ-c)

Comment: The downvote is because there's a built-in way to do this that doesn't involve code. Using the `<authorization>` element. Is there a reason _not_ to use it?

Comment: Purely because he was looking for a way to process the list of Roles, so I suggested a programmatic way to process roles. But no, if that's not a requirement then there is no reason not to use your method.

Comment: Sorry I__, I can't do live chat presently :(